# Two splines comparison

Tags: highcharts

I'm trying to display two splines (xAsis: Date, yAxis: Number) in one plot for comparision. Problem here that x axis values is totaly different from spline to spline. I need to stack them somehow. I tried to use different x axis, but splines draws one after another. Is there a way to do this using Highstock or Highcharts API?
[Here is screenshot of plot with two axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xN0V3.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use separate `xAxis` for the series:

```
xAxis: [{
    type: 'datetime'
}, {
    type: 'datetime'
}],
series: [{
    type: 'spline',
    data: [...]
}, {
    xAxis: 1,
    type: 'spline',
    data: [...]
}]
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ch9Lu56s/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.spline.xAxis